# WSO2 Developer Studio with XPath extensions

Tags: xpath, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have extented Apache Synapse in WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 with additional XPath variables. In the synapse.properties we point to our new XPath classes:
    synapse.xpath.var.extensions=com.avintis.esb.xpath.CountXpathVariableResolver,com.avintis.esb.xpath.UUIDXpathVariableResolver

**Start with wso2server.bat**  all works fine and the above extensions are working without a problem.

**But starting with the Developer Studio from eclipse**, the server starts fine and works, but our **XPath extensions aren't recogniced and do not work**.

I just saw that the server start arguments does contain our library with the classes and also the correct synapse.properties with the declaration. So what may be wrong here by starting from eclipse?

Environment: WSO2-ESB 4.5.1, Developer Studio 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error with Developer Studio follow the instructions given below.

1. Stop the ESB Server instance if you are running it from Eclipse.
2. Double Click on the ESB Server in the Servers view in Eclipse and it will open up the Eclipse Server Overview editor
3. Click on the "Open Launch Configuration" link button and it will open up the Eclipse Server Launch configuration dialog.
4. Switch "Arguments" tab and add `-Dconf.location="<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf"` to the VM Argements section. Make sure to replace the `<ESB_HOME>` section with your actual server location. For E.g: `-Dconf.location="/home/harshana/wso2esb-4.5.1/repository/conf"`
5. Start the ESB instance in Dev Studio and try out the variables

Now you should be able to use it without any issues.

/Harshana